# Listview within a Fragment within a navigation drawer layout - causes version error

Tags: android, list, fragment

a ListView within a Fragment within a Navigation Drawer Layout produce an error in eclipse - Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627
Java - java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)

Error -
Exception raised during rendering: android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

Start with an empty layout - activity_main.xml below

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment1" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#111"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" 
            />
    </fragment>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

-- manifest file below --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.listwithinfragment"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: "Unsupported major.minor version 51"

Compile your project with JDK 1.7

Comment: did that but now I am getting other java compilation errors...

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but without additional details it would be hard to help. 
It usually helps me to set default JDK to 1.7 in Eclipse references and and "-noverify" argument for VM.